# Can't add data to existing entry in database

Tags: php, mysql

If i try this is doesn't work:

```
<?php
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/contact/config.inc.php');

$hash = hash('md5', $_POST["password"]);

$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);

mysql_select_db($database, $connection);

mysql_query("UPDATE data
SET password=" . $hash . 
"WHERE id=" . $_POST["id"]);

mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

The data just won't show up in the database. I tried setting the hash and id to a fixed value, still didn't work. I am sure the database connection works, as it works in other scripts. And all variables show up correctly when i `echo` them.

I'm new to PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Put the SQL in a variable like $sql = "UPDATE data SET password= '" . $hash . "' WHERE id='" . $_POST["id"]."'"; and the mysql_query($sql); Now you can make a echo $sql;exit; and know what if your SQL is broken.

Comment: You are begging for some SQL insertions with this...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `quotes` surrounding the values,

```
mysql_query("UPDATE data SET password='" . $hash . "' WHERE id='" . $_POST["id"] . "'") ;
```

**Note:** Mysql extensions are deprecated. Please use Mysqli_* or PDO extensions.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why, is because you are escaping your query incorrectly, you are missing the quotes around your variables.

Change this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE data
SET password=" . $hash . 
"WHERE id=" . $_POST["id"]);
```

To This:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE data
SET password='" . $hash . 
"' WHERE id='" . $_POST["id"] ."'");
```

and whilst typing this, I noticed you did not go back into your query to close your escape.

Notice I have added quotes and went back into the query to close the quotes.